# jquery animate doesn't work correctly when toggled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code. The first bit of code - the individual animation, works as expected - the div reduces to 50%.

The toggle on the other hand causes the div to disappear - seemingly reducing both width and height until the div is no longer visible. It reappears the same way.

I'm no jquery expert - any ideas?

```
    // works
    $(".test-wrapper").animate({
           width: "50%"
       }, 400);

    // Doesn't work
    $(".test-wrapper").toggle(
    function () {

        $(this).animate({
            width: "50%"
        }, 400);
    },
    function () {
        $(this).animate({
            width: "100%"
        }, 400);
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried to figure out what's $(this) inside the functions? It could be that the object "this" is referring to is not the object you want.

Comment: Which jquery version are you using? There is http://api.jquery.com/toggle/ and http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Comment: @legendofawesomeness i've replaced this with the selector - something is amiss an alert doesn't trigger inside the first toggle function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `click` instead:

```
$(".test-wrapper").click(function () {
    $(this).animate({
        width: !this.toggled ? "50%" : "100%"
    }, 400);
    this.toggled = !this.toggled;
});
```

You are surely using jQuery version 1.9> so using instead of this removed one [toogle event](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)

this [one (toggle)](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

Comment: Good spot with the removal - using 2.1

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's toggle isn't the same thing as animate. Toggle just hide/display the element. [Here's the doc](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

To achieve what you're doing you would need to define 2 differents animations and use a test somehow to know which one you need to run.